Zygote Crash caused by services.jar
I'm a porter and I wanted to port XperiaUI (Xperia 10 II), it manages to boot, but it stays on bootloop, here the link of logcat error : https://justpaste.it/gdgp5

Create the Port based on the original Xperia UI firmware, and using Lineage OS Vendor

Package and install and test the Port

You get a bootloop



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
